# How to setup my Tileserver-php

Tags: qgis-3, tiles, php, apache, tile-server

I have downloaded "xampp-windows-x64-7.3.6-3-VC15-installer.exe" and installed only Apache and PHP. My Apache server is running.

I have download "tileserver-php-master" and paste the folder in path of "C:\MyTileServer\htdocs" without any changes.

What will I do to open SAS Planet tiles in PHP? I want to open it in QGIS 3 in LAN network environment. Path for my SAS planet tiles is "D:\SAS.Planet\cache_gmt\vesat.....".  It is tree type folder.

How to proceed for next step.

Comment: More info please. What is SAS Tile? Do you have it as mbtiles or simple folder tree and pictures?

Comment: @GSienko I have SAS planet tiles and these are in tree folder. Eg. D:\SAS.Planet\cache_gmt\vesat\z3\3\5.png.